# Why is the QGIS print composer scale bar not right?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I went to re-do a map (of quite a large area of the globe) that I had already created, yet when I added the scale bar in the values were different and they definitely don't look correct, whereas before they were. The original map the scale bar went up to 8000km, which was correct, but now the same scale bar has the largest value of 1200km, when it should be 8000.

Unfortunately I overided the previous version of the exported PDF so I can't restore it.

I hope this makes sense.